# Correct use of Cont declaration in Mvvm

Tags: c#, mvvm, constants

I need advice please.

In my code (MVVM) I use CONST in this way.

Is it correct or we can write it in a better way?

```
public Int16 MODE = 0;
public const  MODE_APPEND = 1;
public const  MODE_UPDATE = 2;

etc..... 

In main window

if (MODE == MODE_UPDATE) 
  {
    "UPDATE Table_1 Set 0 to ......"
  }

In other window

if (MODE == MODE_APPEND) 
  {
    "INSERT Table_1 ......"
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use enums instead of constants

```
enum Modes
{
    None = 0,
    Append = 1,
    Update = 2
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How do you modify `MODE`? Is the code from your example located in a `ViewModel`?

If you modify `MODE` via a `View` (e.g. `ComboBox`) then it is *WRONG* to update Database tables in a `ViewModel`!

If it is located in a *Repository* (or something like this) go for *SEPARATE METHODES* - there is no actual need for a switch statement!